# Why isn't my element being added to the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a input element on the DOM tree with an attribute of type=text with jQuery. However it seems to not work. The DOM tree is the same and no console errors.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $code = $("#command");
  var $text = $("#itemtext");
  var $count = $('#count');
  var $add = $('add');

  $add.click(function() {
    $("#items").last().after('<input type="text" id="itemtext" />');
  });
  $("#generatebutton").click(function() {
    $code.text('/give @p bundle{Items:[{id:' + $text.val() + ',Count:' + $count.val() + '}]}');

  });
});
```

```html
<body>
  <h1 id="title">Bundle Generator for mc</h1>
  <div id="items">
    <input type="text" placeholder="item name" id="itemtext">
    <input type="number" min="-128" max="127" id="count">
    <button id="addslot">Add slot</button>
    <button id="generatebutton">Generate!</button>
  </div>
  <h2>Your command is here!</h2>
  <p id="command"></p>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

this line:

```
$("#items").last().after('<input type="text" id="itemtext" />');
```

doesn't work, can anyone help me?

Comment: There is no `.append` here

Comment: Why are you running such an ancient jQuery version? You can probably update to 3.x with no issues.

Comment: `last()` is meaningless on `$('#items')` since there will only ever be one.

Comment: `$('add')` isn't going to select anything as there are no `add` elements in the page.

Comment: Typo: `var $add = $('add');` should be `var $add = $('#addslot');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mentioned an `id` that isn't in DOM. Maybe you are looking for `addslot` instead of `add`? Also there is no indication of id ('#') in `var $add = $('add')`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $code = $("#command");
  var $text = $("#itemtext");
  var $count = $('#count');
  var $add = $('#addslot');

  $add.click(function() {
    $("#items").last().after('<input type="text" id="itemtext" />');
  });
  $("#generatebutton").click(function() {
    $code.text('/give @p bundle{Items:[{id:' + $text.val() + ',Count:' + $count.val() + '}]}');

  });
});
```

```html
<body>
  <h1 id="title">Bundle Generator for mc</h1>
  <div id="items">
    <input type="text" placeholder="item name" id="itemtext">
    <input type="number" min="-128" max="127" id="count">
    <button id="addslot">Add slot</button>
    <button id="generatebutton">Generate!</button>
  </div>
  <h2>Your command is here!</h2>
  <p id="command"></p>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
```